# pandas remove spaces from Series

Tags: pandas, series

The question is, how to gain access to the strings inside of the first column so that string manipulations can be performed with each value. For example remove spaces in front of each string.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("adult.csv", sep='\t', index_col=0)
series = data['workclass'].value_counts()
print(series)
```

[image]

Here is the file:
[Zipped csv file](https://easyupload.io/tx0uf9)

Answer (score 1):

It is index, so use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with `series.index`:

```
series.index = series.index.str.strip()
```

But if need convert `series` here to `2 columns DataFrame` use:

```
df = series.rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
```

Comment: This works fine for the first column indeed, but what if you have the same issue with the second column? How do you access the second column?

Comment: Can you try `data = pd.read_csv("adult.csv", sep='\t', index_col=0, skipinitialspace=True)` ?